# abortController is not working on safari to abort a request

Tags: javascript, browser, safari, cross-browser, navigator

i have this code for requesting webAuthn authentication and i wanna abort the request after a few seconds if the user didn't authenticate.

```
const abortController = new AbortController();
const abortTimer = setTimeout(() => abortController.abort('ABORTED'), 5000);
const { signal } = abortController;
navigator.credentials
  .create({ publicKey, signal })
  .then((newCredInfo) => {
    const webAuthNResString = publicKeyCredentialToJSON(newCredInfo);
    clearTimeout(abortTimer);
    submintWebAuthNData(webAuthNResString, 'create');
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    logger({
      name: 'REGISTRATION_FAILED',
      error
    });
    clearTimeout(abortTimer);
  });
```

and this works fine in chromium based browsers but on safari it doesn't abort the request. and i saw on documentation that latest safari version support abort controller.

is there a different implementation for safari? or am i missing something?

Comment: Did you see any errors in the console?

Comment: This won't solve your problem, but it's good to know: if you need an AbortSignal to fire after a timeout, you can now use [`AbortSignal.timeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal/timeout_static) in [most modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_abortsignal_timeout)

Comment: @code no there is no error on the console

Comment: One more observation here the abort signal is invoked and the promise is rejected but the (figure print/ face id) scan dialog is not closed so the user still think they can scan. on chrome not only the promise is rejected the dialog is also closed automatically when the abort signal is invoked

Comment: I also encountered a similar problem. Did you find a solution to your problem that you can tell us about?